# multiple background colors for an image

Tags: html, css, image

What I am looking to achieve is to display an image with a transparent background layer, this image would sit over a background which would have a white border and gray box centred in the image area.

Basically to give the image a partial gray background, then to leave the rest white, to give the appearance of the image to "float" over the gray background as well as allow me to make simple css changes to change the background verses having to redo the images to change the look.

[image: example of the look I am trying to achieve]

this is the css I have tried:

```
.borderlist img {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;  
    background:
        linear-gradient
          (255,255,255, 0.9),
        url('../images/gray.png') no-repeat;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;

}


And the html:

 <a href="http://www.domain.com/bounty.html"><span class="borderlist"><img src="images/bounty.png" alt="BOUNTY" title=" BOUNTY " width="225" height="155"></span><br>BOUNTY </a>
```

Comment: do  you have some code ?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question? That way, it will look better (with proper line ends and such). Anyway, the answer is probably to use a gradient.

Comment: your html is broken, can you please fix that ?

Comment: fixed and added into the original question...

Comment: @Peter Don't forget to mark the most helpful response as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I removed the underline from the `<a>` because it creates a weird underline on the `<br>`. If you want the text to be underlined, you could throw it in a `<span>` with a class that tells it to have it. but this is what I got. Let me know if you're needing it to do something different.

```css
.overflowing-img {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.undrline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.borderlist {
  text-align: center;
}
.borderlist img {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(160,160,160, 0.5), rgba(160,160,160, 0.5));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80% auto;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.domain.com/bounty.html" class="overflowing-img">
  <span class="borderlist">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/gift_PNG5950.png" alt="BOUNTY" title=" BOUNTY " width="225" height="155">
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="undrline">BOUNTY<span>
</a>
```

Comment: Three great answers, thanks everyone, I see what I need to do, I appreciate all the help everyone has put forth :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a different image, but is this what you are attempting to achieve?

```css
.borderlist img {
  width: 200;
  height: 100;
}

.borderlist {
  width: 225px;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c8c8c8, #ffffff);
  margin: auto;
}

.whiteBorder {
  width: 255px;
  height: 155px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="whiteBorder">
  <div class="borderlist">
  <a href="http://www.domain.com/bounty.html">
    <img src="http://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png" alt="BOUNTY" title="BOUNTY">
    <br>BOUNTY</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that, no luck though.

Comment: Thanks, the gray background you have is larger then image, I need a smaller gray background with a white border (as is seen above), your background is larger then the wiki image...

Comment: I understand. The point was that you can use layered divs in the background to get the "white border" (sized as the largest div) then use a smaller one centered inside the larger with the grey gradient that holds the image. Adjust the sizes as you need, but you should be able to see the methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing using `:before` in your css to overlay the image on top of a div.

```css
div{
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 20px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
div:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: -20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLzG5.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Three great answers, thanks everyone, I see what I need to do, I appreciate all the help everyone has put forth :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets go very simple first:

You can't move the image to left by changing css though

```css
.borderlist { 
    background: grey;
    border: 60px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderlist">
<img src="https://s9.postimg.org/d0odjmlcv/dwa.png" height="100px" width="150px" />
</div>
```

You can do this too, create a container div, inside, create the grey div, then float the image above the grey div, like this (I think this is the best):

```css
.borderlist {
    padding: 5%;
    background: white;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.grey {
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  width: 130px;
  height: 90px;  
  margin: 10px;
}

.float {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderlist">
<div class="grey">
</div>
<img class="float" src="https://s9.postimg.org/d0odjmlcv/dwa.png" height="100px" width="150px" />
</div>
```

Feel free to change and play around to understand it properly

Comment: Three great answers, thanks everyone, I see what I need to do, I appreciate all the help everyone has put forth :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using a mask (white colored background covering the edges), you could use multiple backgrounds coupled with a background color. (credit to user [Dave Cripps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078025/dave-cripps) for the demo image that I shamelessly stole from his demo for mine.)

```css
a {
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}

.borderlist {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;  
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, white 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 85%, white 85%), linear-gradient(to bottom, white 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 85%, white 85%);
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;

}

a:hover .borderlist {
  background-color: #5C5;
}

.borderlist img {
  height:auto;

}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.domain.com/bounty.html"><span class="borderlist"><img src="http://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png " alt="BOUNTY" title=" BOUNTY " width="225" height="155"></span><br>BOUNTY </a>
```

Comment: I shamelessly stole the image from Wikipedia so it's all good! :)